# How to see map when i launch nominatim?

Tags: postgresql, apache, ubuntu-16.04, nominatim

When I open http://[IP]/nominatim/ I get only code

I've installed via tips from that link https://nominatim.org/release-docs/latest/admin/Installation/ and also made data import.
And all I see when I open this link is that code.

```
getPreferredLanguages(); $oGeocode->setLanguagePreference($aLangPrefOrder); if (CONST_Search_ReversePlanForAll || isset($aLangPrefOrder['name:de']) || isset($aLangPrefOrder['name:ru']) || isset($aLangPrefOrder['name:ja']) || isset($aLangPrefOrder['name:pl']) ) { $oGeocode->setReverseInPlan(true); } // Format for output $sOutputFormat = $oParams->getSet('format', array('html', 'xml', 'json', 'jsonv2', 'geojson', 'geocodejson'), 'html'); $sForcedGeometry = ($sOutputFormat == 'html') ? 'geojson' : null; $oGeocode->loadParamArray($oParams, $sForcedGeometry); if (CONST_Search_BatchMode && isset($_GET['batch'])) { $aBatch = json_decode($_GET['batch'], true); $aBatchResults = array(); foreach ($aBatch as $aBatchParams) { $oBatchGeocode = clone $oGeocode; $oBatchParams = new Nominatim\ParameterParser($aBatchParams); $oBatchGeocode->loadParamArray($oBatchParams); $oBatchGeocode->setQueryFromParams($oBatchParams); $aSearchResults = $oBatchGeocode->lookup(); $aBatchResults[] = $aSearchResults; } include(CONST_BasePath.'/lib/template/search-batch-json.php'); exit; } $oGeocode->setQueryFromParams($oParams); if (!$oGeocode->getQueryString() && isset($_SERVER['PATH_INFO']) && $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'][0] == '/' ) { $sQuery = substr(rawurldecode($_SERVER['PATH_INFO']), 1); // reverse order of '/' separated string $aPhrases = explode('/', $sQuery); $aPhrases = array_reverse($aPhrases); $sQuery = join(', ', $aPhrases); $oGeocode->setQuery($sQuery); } $hLog = logStart($oDB, 'search', $oGeocode->getQueryString(), $aLangPrefOrder); $aSearchResults = $oGeocode->lookup(); if ($sOutputFormat=='html') { $sDataDate = chksql($oDB->getOne("select TO_CHAR(lastimportdate,'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI')||' GMT' from import_status limit 1")); } logEnd($oDB, $hLog, count($aSearchResults)); $sQuery = $oGeocode->getQueryString(); $aMoreParams = $oGeocode->getMoreUrlParams(); if ($sOutputFormat != 'html') $aMoreParams['format'] = $sOutputFormat; if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'])) { $aMoreParams['accept-language'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']; } $sMoreURL = CONST_Website_BaseURL.'search.php?'.http_build_query($aMoreParams); if (CONST_Debug) exit; $sOutputTemplate = ($sOutputFormat == 'jsonv2') ? 'json' : $sOutputFormat; include(CONST_BasePath.'/lib/template/search-'.$sOutputTemplate.'.php');
```

Local.php in build directory

```
<?php
@define('CONST_Database_Web_User', 'apache');
@define('CONST_Website_BaseURL', 'http://geocoder.cloudapp.net/');
@define('CONST_Postgresql_Version', '9.5');
@define('CONST_Postgis_Version', '2.2.1');
```

Also i've had added  it in apache conf

```
<Directory "/srv/nominatim/Nominatim-3.2.0/website">
Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AddType text/html   .php
DirectoryIndex search.php
Require all granted
</Directory>
Alias /nominatim /srv/nominatim/Nominatim-3.2.0/website
```

I expect to see map, not code.